# How to Increment different rows with different values in one query SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

This is my `user_wallets` table:

| id | balance |
| --- | --- |
| A | 70 |
| B | 40 |

I want to increment balance of user A with `30` and balance of user B with `10` in a single query.

and I want to know whether it's possible in TypeORM or not. ( raw SQL will do the trick for me as well )

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `values` like this:

```
update t
    set t.balance = t.balance + v.inc
    from (values ('A', 30), ('B', 10)) v(user, inc)
    where t.user = v.user;
```

Putting all the changes in `values()` makes the query easy to maintain (adding new users, for instance).  It is also much less cumbersome than a big `case` expression.  **And** the `where` clause filters down only to the rows that are changing.